# Create Vertical Divider Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

How to create vertical dividers with Jetpack Compose? I try to use Spacer and Box to do it, but it doesn't show up at all. Here is what i tried:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .width(2.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Black)
)
```

But that doesn't work at all. So how to do vertical divider in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: you just forgot to specify `.height(1.dp)`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use the [**`Divider`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Divider(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) composable with the `width(xx.dp)` modifier applying an [**intrinsic measurements**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) to its parent container.

Something like:

```
Row(Modifier
    .height(IntrinsicSize.Min) //intrinsic measurements
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .background(Color.Yellow)
) {
        Text("First Text")

        Divider(
            color = Color.Red,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()  //fill the max height
                .width(1.dp)
        )

        Text("Second text")
}
```

[image]

As explained in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements):

> The Row composable's `minIntrinsicHeight` will be the maximum `minIntrinsicHeight` of its children. The `Divider` element's `minIntrinsicHeight` is `0` as it doesn't occupy space if no constraints are given; the `TextField` `minIntrinsicHeight` will be that of the content given a specific width. Therefore, the `Row` element's height constraint will be the max `minIntrinsicHeight` of the `TextField`s content. The `Divider` will then expand its height to the height constraint given by the `Row`.

Comment: Can you explain why the intrinsic is needed? i read the Layouts in Compose docs but still dont get it

Comment: @wiryadev It is not needed, for example if you have a fixed height. But if you want to obtain a layout such as reported in the answer without fixing the height you have to use it.

Comment: how to add elevation for this divider

Comment: thanks a lot I wasted 2 hours for this

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It's working when i added .height(IntrinsicSize.Min) modifier in RowScope

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Perfect example with great explanations for this.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a `VerticalDivider` Composable, which you can use the same way as the built-in `Divider` horizontal one.

```
@Composable
fun VerticalDivider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = DividerAlpha),
    thickness: Dp = 1.dp
) {
    Box(
        modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(thickness)
            .background(color = color)
    )
}

private const val DividerAlpha = 0.12f
```

Comment: This seems the best handful custom divider vertical divider snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BOX` ,`SPACER` or `DIVIDER` to create a vertical divider

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp)) {
    Text("TEXT 1")
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(2.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
    )

    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(2.dp)
            .background(Color.Black)
    )

    Divider(color = Color.Blue, modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .width(2.dp))
    Text("TEXT 2")
}
```

Code result:

[image: Code result]

Answer (score 0):

composable has been a function `rotate` in Modifier object, so just rotate to 90 degree to your Divider compose

```
Divider(
    modifier = Modifier
               .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
               .rotate(90f),
    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline
)
```