# How can I display vertical divider in Row?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add a vertical line to separate my 2 buttons but when I do this the line goes all the way to the bottom of the screen and I lose the Data content. But I want the line to go just after the button cap (they are not really buttons, they are text boxes).

How can I make the vertical line go to where I mark with the red line?

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar( /* Config*/ )
        },

        content = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                Column {

                    OptionButtons()
                    Divider()
                    Data( /* Component with a list with data */ )
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

```
@Composable
fun OptionButtons() {

    Row {

        Text(
            text = "Option1",
            color = OptionButtonText,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.50f)
                .padding(
                    PaddingValues(
                        start = 20.dp,
                        top = 12.dp,
                        end = 20.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp
                    )
                )
                .clickable { }
        )

        Divide()

        Text(
            text = "Option2",
            color = OptionButtonText,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.50f)
                .padding(
                    PaddingValues(
                        start = 20.dp,
                        top = 12.dp,
                        end = 20.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp
                    )
                )
                .clickable { }
        )
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Vertical Divider Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919041/create-vertical-divider-jetpack-compose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this `modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`  in the `Row` to get minimum space for `Row`:

```
@Composable
fun OptionButtons() {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "Option1",
            color = Color.Red,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.50f)
                .padding(
                    PaddingValues(
                        start = 20.dp,
                        top = 12.dp,
                        end = 20.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp
                    )
                )
                .clickable { }
        )
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(1.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        )
        Text(
            text = "Option2",
            color = Color.Red,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(0.50f)
                .padding(
                    PaddingValues(
                        start = 20.dp,
                        top = 12.dp,
                        end = 20.dp,
                        bottom = 12.dp
                    )
                )
                .clickable { }
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's just what I needed, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have your text divider and text within a Row{ } block.

What you need to do is to structure it like this

```
Column{
Row{
Text()
Divider()
Text()
}
Divider()
Row{
Text()
Divider()
Text()
}

}
```

```
@Composable
fun OptionButtons() {
    Column {
        Row {
            Text(
                text = "Option1",
                color = OptionButtonText,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.50f)
                    .padding(
                        PaddingValues(
                            start = 20.dp,
                            top = 12.dp,
                            end = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 12.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .clickable { },
            )
            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(1.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Option2",
                color = OptionButtonText,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.50f)
                    .padding(
                        PaddingValues(
                            start = 20.dp,
                            top = 12.dp,
                            end = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 12.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .clickable { },
            )
        }

        Divider(color = Color.Red, thickness = 1.dp)
        
        Row {
            Text(
                text = ""//whatever value you want to populate with 
                        textAlign = TextAlign . Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.50f)
                    .padding(
                        PaddingValues(
                            start = 20.dp,
                            top = 12.dp,
                            end = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 12.dp
                        )
                    )

            )
            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(1.dp)
            )

            Text(
                text = ""//whatever value you want to populate with 
                        textAlign = TextAlign . Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(0.50f)
                    .padding(
                        PaddingValues(
                            start = 20.dp,
                            top = 12.dp,
                            end = 20.dp,
                            bottom = 12.dp
                        )
                    )

            )
        }


    }


}

}
```

Comment: But I want a vertical line too between both buttons. With this approach, there are not vertical line

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: No, with de above answer I lose the data section. Only show the OptionButton, the Data section is missing

Comment: Edited the answer. Pls Check